# Finding the largest element in array by using foreach loop

Tags: java, arrays

I read about a foreach loop and I tried to find the largest element in the Array, but it did not work as the usual one. I was wondering what the difference is?

```
public void foreachloop()
{
    int[] T = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    int x = T[0];

    for (int element : T) {
        if (T[element] > x) {
            x = T[element];
        }
    }

    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Comment: `element` represents the whole element of the array, not its index

Comment: `if (element > x) x = element;`

Comment: Don't use single capital letters for variable names. `T` is typically used as a generic type argument.

Comment: This is where stepping through the code in your debugger should have been the fastest way to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `for (int element: T)`, the variable `element` runs through each value in `T`. So you shouldn't be trying to look at the value `T[element]` - just `element` itself.

Like so:

```
for (int element: T) {
    if (element > x) x = element;
}
```

If you try and access `T[element]` when `element` is 7, an exception is thrown because 7 is not a valid index for your array. (Valid indices are 0 to 6.)

Answer (score 2):

1. Initialize `max` to be the smallest Integer possible
2. Using the for-each loop check if the current element is larger than `max` and if so make that the new value of `max`
3. Return `max` after the for-each loop is finished

Personally I would create a separate method for this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = new int[]{1,2,3};
    System.out.println("The array looks like: " + Arrays.toString(arr)); //The array looks like: [1, 2, 3]
    System.out.println("The max of the array is: " + arrayMax(arr)); //The max of the array is: 3
  }

  public static int arrayMax (int[] arr) {
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE; //initilize max to the smallest integer possible
    for(int element: arr)
        max = Math.max(max, element);
    return max;
  }
}
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/FMCi/1)

Answer (score 1):

When you are using foreach, first you define what is the type of array (here it is `int`), then you give an arbitary name (you chose `element`), then `:`, and then the name of array. After that you can access to elements using the name that you chose.

```
public void foreachloop()
{
    int[] T = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    int x = T[0];

    for (int element : T) {
        if (element > x) {
            x = element;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(x);
}
```